# How to use custom error messages in Hibernate Validator without spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

Is it possible to have custom error messages in separate file without using spring framework?
I'm developing API using hibernate 5+, jersey, jackson and `hibernate-validator 5.2.2.Final` for valdiation. I have found that i need to do declaration of file with custom error messages, but i don't where to do it.

How my code should look like by examples:

```
public class Account {

    private int id;
        @NotNull(message = "{account.name.null}")
        @Length(min = 1, max = 150, message = "{account.name.length}")
    private String name;
        @NotNull(message = "{account.lastname.null}")
        @Length(min = 1, max = 150, message = "{account.lastname.length}")
    private String lastName;
```

with errorMessages.xml file with structure as:

```
account.name.null= Name value is missing.
account.name.length= Name has to be between {min} and {max}.
```

#### Tested approach

I have tried it with static final variables, but i can not use methods to return messages:

```
public class ValidationMessages {

    //ACCOUNT
    public static String ACCOUNT_NAME_LENGTH(int min, int max)
    {
        return "Name has to be between "+min+" and "+max+".";
    } 
    public static final String ACCOUNT_NAME_NULL = "Name value is missing.";


public class Account {

    private int id;
        @NotNull(message = ValidationMessages.ACCOUNT_NAME_NULL)
        @Length(min = 1, max = 150 message =ValidationMessages.ACCOUNT_NAME_LENGTH(1,150))
    private String name;
        @NotNull(message = ValidationMessages.ACCOUNT_LASTNAME_NULL)
        @Length(min = 1, max = 150 message = ValidationMessages.ACCOUNT_NAME_LENGTH(1,150))
    private String lastName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errorMessages.xml` had to been renamed to `.properties` and i had to move it to `/resources` folder